# pthread_cond_timedwait hanging with gdb

Tags: gdb, pthreads

I'm using `pthread_cond_timedwait` on a thread loop to execute at every X ms (unless it is waked first).

When I'm using gdb to debug it sometimes it the function never returns.

[This forum post](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.development.apps/2008-06/msg00117.html) also have the same problem, but there is no solution.

Here's some code that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static pthread_cond_t s_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t s_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc = 0;
    struct timespec curts = { 0 }; /* transformed timeout value */

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &curts);
    curts.tv_sec += 10; /* Add 10 seconds to current time*/

    pthread_mutex_lock(&s_mutex);

    printf("pthread_cond_timedwait\n");
    rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&s_cond, &s_mutex, &curts);
    if (rc == ETIMEDOUT)
    {
        printf("Timer expired \n");
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_mutex);

    return 1;
}
```

If I run it, it will run OK, and if I run in gdb it will also run OK.

I've narrowed down to these steps (I've named the program `timedTest` ):

1. Run the program;
2. While it runs attach gdb to it;
3. Execute `continue` on gdb;
4. The `timedTest` program never returns...;

Then, if I hit `Ctrl+C` on the terminal running gdb and run `continue` again, then the program will return.

I can probably use some other method to achieve what I want in this case, but I assume that it should be a solution to this problem.

**EDIT:**

Looks like this only happens in some machines, so maybe there's something to do with gcc / glibc / gdb / kernel versions...

Versions where this happens almost always:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-0ubuntu13) 2.13

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2

$ uname -a
Linux geovani 2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 05:17:09 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Does `info threads` show anything interesting on the stuck thread?

Comment: How often does that occur? I'm trying to reproduce it, but so far it has not happened in 10 attempts.

Comment: It happens almost always, but maybe this to have something to do with some versions of gdb or glibc or even the linux kernel... (added versions to the post)

Comment: @Michael: `info threads` always show `__kernel_vsyscall()` as the current execution point. Backtrace is: `main ()` -> `pthread_cond_timedwait ()` -> `pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()` -> `__kernel_vsyscall ()`

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on Fedora 14 x86_64 (SMP) nor Fedora 12 ARM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1125638), this is a **bug in the 2.6.38 kernel**. I've made some tests with a 2.6.39 kernel and problem does not happen. Rolling back to the 2.6.38 it appears again.

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy trying to figure this out